# Recognize loop for in other python scripts

Tags: python-3.x

First: sorry for my English!

I'm trying to write a python script that can recognize any loop for in other python scripts.

```
import re

with open('boite_a_fonctions_v3_1.py', 'r') as f:
    text=f.read()
    a = text.split(" ")
    #print (a)

    loop = re.compile(r'for"(.*):\t(.*)"')

    def find_loop(a):
        c = []
        for line in a:
            c += loop.findall(line)
        print (c)

    #find_loop(a)
```

I have nothing as a result (which already makes me happy, no mistakes !!). Anyone have any suggestions?

A part of the code 'boite_a_fonctions_v3_1.py':

```
fidr.seek(0)
reg = compile(fmt.get_motif())
id = 0
for line in fidr :  
    for seg in reg.findall(line) :
        if id == tokenId :
            mot, etq = seg
            return mot, etq
        else :
            id += 1
return None

def get_tokens(fid, fmt, tokenIds):
    if isinstance(tokenIds, int):
        try :
            return get_token(fid,fmt, tokenIds)
        except :
            return None
    else:
        n = None
        for id in tokenIds:
            try:
                n = len(get_token(fid,fmt, id))
                break
            except:
                pass
        if not n :
            return None

        ret = list()
        for i in range(n) :
            tmp = list()
            for id in tokenIds :
                try:
                    tmp.append(get_token(fid,fmt,id)[i])
                except:
                    pass
            ret.append(tmp)
         return ret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though i am not experienced but i think this should give you output.
Make a multi line string variable with name "rr" in this case and run this code
and put all your file text in it as a multi line string

```
   import re
   rr="""All your input string here"""
   print(len(re.findall(r'for(.*):(.*)',rr,re.M)))
```